# How to change shell from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, zsh

I am trying to change from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh but I get this...

```
$ chsh
Password:
Changing the login shell for user_name
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
Login Shell [/bin/bash]: /bin/zsh
chsh: user 'username' does not exist in /etc/passwd
$
```

I checked /etc/passwd, there is no entry for my username. Also, we use likewise-open for authentication on LDAP.

Please help.

Comment: You'll need to find out what is controlling your login shell if it isn't an `/etc/passwd` entry and change that. It might be an LDAP field or it might be something hard-coded in the pam/auth module in use here or it might be something configurable via your home directory. Someone familiar with likewise-open might know.

Comment: This is something your sysadmin will need to answer.  But you could, as a work around, exec zsh from .profile.  Not that I'd recommend that, as it's fragile.  I would instead just run or exec zsh manually at login.

Comment: If NIS is at play, try `ypchsh`. A similar question about changing shells is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/how-to-change-from-csh-to-bash-as-default-shell