# Change cloud9 ide's terminal's shell (I want zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I've installed the cloud9 sdk on an archlinux, and I'd like to have zsh when I open a terminal, instead of bash. In the mean time I'm just launching zsh manually, but I want this to be automatic. I tried to make a `.bashrc` whith only `zsh` inside, but bash doesn't use that `.bashrc`.

Any idea on how to do this?

EDIT :
Since editing `/etc/bashrc` doesn't work and neither does the command `usermod -s /bin/zsh <user>`, I think that cloud9 sdk uses something else...

Comment: Putting `zsh` at the top of my `.bashrc` worked for me! Although this is with AWS Cloud9, so that may be different...

Answer (score 0):

you could try in `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile` but that would be a hack.

Best would be to change user prefered shell in `/etc/password`

related: [How to change shell from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843314/how-to-change-shell-from-bin-bash-to-bin-zsh)

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post.